# VSCODE terminal settings configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, anaconda

I am able to run streamlit and python on Anaconda cmd prompt on a separte window, but I can't get the streamlit to run on the VSCODE terminal (python runs fine). When I type in `streamlit` in the terminal, it generates a message saying

```
'streamlit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am guessing if I can get my VSCode terminal to run as Anaconda prompt, it should run streamlit without an error, as I am able to run streamlit on a separate Anaconda prompt outside of VSCode.

I am using Python 3.9.5 64-bit as my interpreter on VSCode and selected Command Prompt for my terminal option. I am on Windows environment.

I tried selecting Python 3.8.5 ('base') as my interpreter, but it threw the same message. Here is the image of the options I have for interpreter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a new command prompt on VSCode that's using 3.8.5 ('base': conda) as my interpreter in order to successfully run streamlit!!